# Enabling htaccess file for codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, apache2, opensuse

I'm trying to have htaccess work on codeigniter project but the module is not working and I don't know how to enable rewrite module. To have read the htaccess. The OS is Opensuse 12.2.

I have this directive in the default-server.conf

Alias /safememoirs/ /home/gabriele/Web/safememoirs/

Options Indexes MultiViews
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all

But I don't understand

A) how to enable the module 
B) Where should I put the .htaccess directive id in the default-server.conf or in the site directory?
C) This is for the localhost, what happen when I go online?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand exactly what your question was, but here is my htaccess file for removing the index.php in the url. 
it should be place in the root folder.

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|bjs|plugins|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```